# Submitted Angular form shows up as null in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I have a form that submits *author*, *context* and *images* (recently added) in Angular. When I output the data sent over, I was able to get *author* and *context*, however I cannot get *images* (it always display *null*).

**=== SpringBoot ===**
Model:

```
public class Content {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String context;
    private String author;
    private String images;

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public String getContext() { return context; }
    public String getAuthor() { return author; }
    public String getImage() { return images; }
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
@ResponseBody
public Content saveContent(@ModelAttribute Content content){
    System.out.println(content.getImages());
    System.out.println(content.getAuthor());
    return null;
}
```

**=== Angular ===**
home.component.ts:

```
submitForm() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('author', 'John Smith');
    formData.append('images', 'sample.png');

    this.http.post<any>('/create', formData).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          console.log('Success');
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        },
    })
}
```

**=== MySQL ===**
[Database columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Ewe.png)

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter in angular post request is body.
Because of that you need to use in your spring controller another annotation *RequestBody* instead *ModelAttribute*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular as a client, so your backend should expose rest APIs to let the clients able to consume them.

***To fix your issue you have to follow these steps:***

**1)** First of all, you have to use a RestController and not a simple controller to map the response into a view. Your controller must be annotated with @RestController

**2)** Change your code like this (bind a request body using the annotation @RequestBody)

```
@RestController // this is the right annotation to use
public class ContentController {
  @PostMapping("/create")
  public Content saveContent(@RequestBody Content content){
  //put your persistence logic (save in a database, ...)
  return content;
  }
}
```

**3)** Create a class called `Content` to define the fields that your backend expects like this

```
export class Content {
  author: string;
  images: string;
}
```

**4)** Change your Angular code to pass directly a request body and not using a FormData

```
submitForm() {
   const contentRequest : Content = {
    author: 'John Smith',
    images: 'sample.png'
}

 this.http.post<any>('/create', contentRequest).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          console.log('Success');
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        },
    })
```

}